# Codeigniter form validation error message

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form on my website header where i allow the user to log in with his username/password... then i POST to /signin page and check if the username exists to allow the user to log in.. if there is a problem upon login i output these errors...

i tried using the following code to show a custom error but with no luck

```
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false){
        $this->load->view("login/index", $data);
    }else{
        $return = $this->_submitLogin();
        if ($return == true){
            //success
        }else{
            $this->form_validation->set_message('new_error', 'error goes here');
            //error
        }
        $this->load->view("login/index", $data);
    }
```

how does set_message work and if this is the wrong method, which one allow me to show a custom error in this case?

**EDIT :**

validation rules:

```
private $validation_rules = array(
    array(
        'field'   => 'username',
        'label'   => 'Username',
        'rules'   => 'trim|required|callback__check_valid_username|min_length[6]|max_length[20]|xss_clean'
    ),
    array(
        'field'   => 'password',
        'label'   => 'Password',
        'rules'   => 'trim|required|min_length[6]|max_length[32]'
    ),
);
```

Comment: How you set your validation rule(s)? Those additional information will necessary. `set_message` method allow you to set your own error messages on the fly. But one thing you should notice, that the key name has to match the  function name that it corresponds to.

Comment: what im trying to do is to show an extra error message when the user enter incorrect login details.

Comment: Additional information which you need to provide is : (i repeat again) how you set your validation rule(s)? Did you use custom callback function? required? unique?

Comment: updated question with validation rules

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `set_message` method allows you to set your own error messages on the fly. But one thing you should notice is that the key name has to match the function name that it corresponds to.

If you need to modify your custom rule, which is `_check_valid_username`, you can do so by perform `set_message` within this function:

```
function _check_valid_username($str)
{
   // Your validation code
   // ...
   // Put this in condition where you want to return FALSE
   $this->form_validation->set_message('_check_valid_username', 'Error Message');
   //
}
```

If you want to change the default error message for a specific rule, you can do so by invoking `set_message` with the first parameter as the rule name and the second parameter as your custom error. E.g., if you want to change the `required` error :

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'Oops this %s is required');
```

If by any chance you need to change the language instead of the error statement itself, create your own `form_validation_lang.php` and put it into the proper language folder inside your system language directory.

Comment: I dont know if im not explaining correctly, i have a form where i post to /signin page and i want to show an error message when $return == false... thats all...

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#individualerrors), you can display the custom error in your view in the following way:

```
<?php echo form_error('new_error'); ?>
```

PS: If this isn't your problem, post your corresponding view code and any other error message that you're getting.

Comment: Err this is to display individual messages, not set custom messages.

Comment: `<?php echo form_error('field_name'); ?>`  where 'field_name' is the name of the field which error has to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your form is already validated in your IF part! You can fix the problem by this way:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == false){
    $this->load->view("login/index", $data);
}else{
    $return = $this->_submitLogin();
    if ($return == true){
        //success
    }else{
        $data['error'] = 'Your error message here';
        //error
    }
    $this->load->view("login/index", $data);
}
```

In the view:

```
    echo $error;
```

The CI way to check user credentials is to use callbacks:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_username_check');

...

public function username_check($str) {
    // your code here
}
```

I recommend you to read CI documentation: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this was to add another validation rule and run the validation again.  That way, I could keep the validation error display in the view consistent.

The following code is an edited excerpt from my working code.

```
public function login() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    $data['content'] = 'login';

    if($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $sql = "select * from users where email = ? and password = ?";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('password')));
        if($query->num_rows()==0) {
            // user not found
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('account', 'Account', 'callback__noaccount');
            $this->form_validation->run();
            $this->load->view('template', $data);
        } else {
            $this->session->set_userdata('userid', $query->id);
            redirect('/home');
        }
    } else {
        $this->load->view('template', $data);
    }
}

public function _noaccount() {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('_noaccount', 'Account must exist');
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Require Codeigniter 3.0**

Using callback_ method;

```
class My_controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->form_validation->set_message('date_control', '%s Date Special Error');
    }

    public function date_control($val, $field) { // for special validate
        if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}$/", $val)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function my_controller_test() {
        if ($this->input->post()) {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('date_field', 'Date Field', 'trim|callback_date_control[date_field]|xss_clean');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                $data['errors']=validation_errors();
                $this->load->view('my_view',$data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

if date = '14.07.2017' *no error*

if date = '14-7-2017' *Date Field Date Special Error*